# Inferring a duration (time) value from two datetime values in separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, date-arithmetic

Consider the following schema definition for table MyTable

TABLE MyTable

```
[Id] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL, -- This is not really a nvarchar type, just simplifying the schema
[PropertyName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[OriginalValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ChangeTimestamp] [datetime] NULL
```

A data example of this table would be:

| Id | PropertyName | OriginalValue | UpdatedValue | ChangeTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | Property1 | Value2 | Value3 | 2022-11-02 02:00:00.000 |
| Id1 | Property1 | Value1 | Value2 | 2022-11-02 01:00:00.000 |

What I'm aiming to do is to create a view that will define a new column [duration] that will give the time a particular setting was activated. Taking the example above, we can see that Value2 was ON for 1hour.

If anyone has done anything similar in the past, I would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: You probably want to explore the use of `LAG`.

Comment: How can we tell when a feature is *activated*, or deactivated? How can we tel that Value2 was ON? You would probably need to provide more details about the logic you want, along with a few more rows of sample data, and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: @GMB if there is a record (row 2 in the example above) in MyTable with the UpdatedValue equals to 'Value2' for 'Property1', consider that value of 'Value2' as activated. That means that in row 1, when the UpdatedValue changed to 'Value3', then 'Value3' is activated, in other words 'Value2' became deactivated in that moment. I will add more records to that example.

In terms of the Expected Result, just assume for now that the view will return exactly the same as the example above plus one extra column with the duration.

Comment: @DaleK I will have a look at ```LAG```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the time difference between consecutive rows, you can use window functions.

For the duration to show up  on the row where a setting is deactivated, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
    datediff(
        second, 
        lag(changeTimestamp) over(partition by id, property order by changeTimestamp), 
        changeTimestamp
    ) duration
from mytable t
```

If you prefer to show the duration ar activation time, then you can look ahead with `lead`:

```
select t.*,
    datediff(
        second, 
        changeTimestamp, 
        lead(changeTimestamp) over(partition by id, property order by changeTimestamp)
    ) duration
from mytable t
```

Note that I assumed that you want to partition your data by group of rows sharing the same id and property. You might want to review that.